# Resolve DNS, export to Excel and HTML, then send mail

Tags: html, excel, email, powershell, powershell-4.0

I was almost done with my script and did some late night editing and written over my old version so I cannot go back.

The script was running fine, still needed some tweaks but now it ha come to a complete halt.

The idea is to GC a list of IP's. Resolve the IP's and place them in an excel sheet. Then save the sheet to htm and xlsx. And finally mailing those to me.

Now it gets stuck on sorting the sheet, saving AND mailing...
Can someone give me some insight on what I did wrong here?

it gets stuck on sorting the sheet, saving AND mailing.

It no longer sorts B3:B$Count:

> Exception calling "Sort" with "1" argument(s): "The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."
>   At C:\Folder\Scripts\Get-IP.ps1:137 char:5
>    + [void] $objRange.Sort($objRange2)
>    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

It no longer saves the xlsx file, but does save the HTM file. It is clearly not overwriting something. I even restarted to make sure.

> Exception calling "SaveAs" with "1" argument(s): "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C://Folder/BlockedIP/HTML/2014-07-08/0BCEF810'. workbook."
>   At C:\Folder\Scripts\Get-IP.ps1:160 char:5
>    + $b.SaveAs("$FileXML")
>    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

And finally, it will no longer send me e-mails:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."
>   At C:\Folder\Scripts\Get-IP.ps1:217 char:13
>    + $SMTP = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($SMTP, 587)
>    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

The script:

```
#Get current date
$Date = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd

#Define all files/Paths.
$Path = "C:/Folder/BlockedIP"
md "$Path/HTML/$Date" -Force
    $path2 = "$Path/HTML/$Date"
$PathWeb = "/HTML/$Date"

#Define File's used or created in this script.
$File = "$Path/IP-$Date.txt"
    $FileHtml = "$Path2/IP-$Date.htm"
    $FileXML = "$Path2/IP-$Date.xlsx"
    $FileHTMLWeb = "$PathWeb/IP-$date.htm"

#Get content from given IP list.
$colComputers = @(get-content $File | Sort -unique)
   $count = $colComputers.Count
       write-output "$Count IP's detected."

#Define error actions.
#$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"

#Open Excel.
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

#Since we want this script to look like it's being used without excel I set it's visibility to false.
$a.visible = $True

#Disable excel confirmations.
$a.DisplayAlerts = $False

#Create sheets in Excel.
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)

#Create a Title for the first worksheet and adjust the font
$row = 1
$Column = 1
target="_parent">Creator'
$c.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "Blocked IP's $Date"
$c.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Size = 18
$c.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
$c.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Name = "Cambria"
$c.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.ThemeFont = 1
$c.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.ThemeColor = 4
$c.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.ColorIndex = 55
$c.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Color = 8210719
$range = $c.Range("a1","e1")
$range.Merge() | Out-Null
$range.VerticalAlignment = -4160

#Define subjects.
$c.Name = "Blocked IP's ($Date)"
$c.Cells.Item(2,1) = "Given IP"
$c.Cells.Item(2,2) = "Resolved DNS"
$c.Cells.Item(2,3) = "Returned IP"
$c.Cells.Item(2,5) = "Company name"

#Define cell formatting from subjects.
$c.Range("A2:E2").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
$c.Range("A2:E2").font.size = 13
$c.Range("A2:E2").Font.ColorIndex = 1
$c.Range("A2:E2").Font.Bold = $True

#Define the usedrange for autofitting.
$d = $c.UsedRange

#Make everything fit in it's cell
$D.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

#Define html code for Excel save to .htm.
$xlExcelHTML = 44

#Define rows to alter in excel.
$iRow = 3
$intRow = 3

#Time to run the script.
foreach ($strComputer in $colComputers)
{
#Place IP's from text in the excel sheet
$c.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $strComputer.ToUpper()
$d.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

#Create a status bar for the script
$i = 1
Write-Progress -Activity `
"Creating a usable 'Blocked IP' list ($i/$count)" `
-PercentComplete ($i/$colComputers.Count*100) `
-Status "Please stand by"

try {
    $dnsresult = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($strComputer)
    }
    catch {
          $dnsresult = "$null"
          }

#Clear screen on every checked IP to remove the 'True' statement.
#cls

#Do something with $dnsresults.

#Display information about host
#Give hostname Entry in Cell2
$c.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $dnsresult.HostName

#IP listed in Cell 3
$c.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = $dnsresult.AddressList[0].IpAddressToString

#Make everything fit in it's cell.
$d.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

#Define row for the IP list.
$intRow = $intRow + 1

#Set background color for the IP list.
$d.Range("A$($iRow):E$($intRow)").interior.colorindex = 15

#Sort all IP's on resolved name.
$objWorksheet = $b.Worksheets.Item(1) 
$objRange = $objWorksheet.UsedRange 
$objRange2 = $objworksheet.Range("B3:B($Count)")  
[void] $objRange.Sort($objRange2) 

#Define borders here.
<# Insert script :D #>

#Define Filters here. (Picking out blank DNS and giving those a name)
<# Insert script :D #>

#Define Filters here. (Picking out specific DNS name and give them color code)
<# Insert script :D #>

#Make everything fit in it's cell.
$d.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null



#Clear screen on every checked IP to remove the 'True' statement.
#cls
}
#Save the file as .xlsx on every placed IP to ensure the file is not lost due to any reason.
$b.SaveAs("$FileXML")

#Save final result as a .htm file
$b.SaveAs("$FileHTML",$xlExcelHTML)

#Close and quit Excel.
$b.Close()
get-process *Excel* | Stop-Process -force

#Move .txt file to the correct HTML folder.
move-item $file $path2 -Force

#Clear screen, again. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Variables for public IP
# I am defining website url in a variable
$url = "http://checkip.dyndns.com" 
# Creating a new .Net Object names a System.Net.Webclient
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
# In this new webdownlader object we are telling $webclient to download the
# url $url 
$IpPublic = $webclient.DownloadString($url)
# Just a simple text manuplation to get the ipadress form downloaded URL
# If you want to know what it contain try to see the variable $IpPublic
$IpPublic2 = $IpPublic.ToString()
$ipPublic3 = $IpPublic2.Split(" ")
$ipPublic4 = $ipPublic3[5]
$ipPublic5 = $ipPublic4.replace("</body>","")
$FinalIPAddress = $ipPublic5.replace("</html>","")

#Variables e-mail.
$From = "Blocked IP <##@g##.com>"
$To = "IT Dept <##@##.nl>"
$CC = "Someone <##r@##.nl"
$SMTP = "smtp.gmail.com"
$Subject = "Blocked IPs for $date ($Count Total)"
#The href should point to the htm file in your iis/apache folder.
$WebLink = $FinalIPAddress+$FileHtmlWeb
$here = "<a href='http://$Weblink'><b>Here</b></a>"
#Define the body of your e-mail, in this case it displays a message and shows the server it is send from with it's local IP.
#A link to the .htm file, how many IP's were blocked and the date of the message.
$Body = "This is an automated message generated by server: $env:COMPUTERNAME, $IP</br></br>
Please see the attachment or click $here to get the $Count blocked IP's of $date. </br>    </br></br>"

#Variables e-mail user.
$username = "##@##.com"
$password = "##"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
$ip = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"').ipaddress[0]

#Clear screen, again. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Send output as e-mail.
$SMTP = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($SMTP, 587) 
$SMTP.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$username", "$password"); 
$SMTP.isbodyhtml= $true
$SMTP.Send($From, $To, $Subject, $FileXML, $Body)

send-mailmessage -BodyAsHtml -from $From -to $To -cc $CC -subject $Subject -Attachments     $FileXML -body $Body -priority High -smtpServer $SMTP -credential ($cred) -usessl


#Create a function to relase Com object at end of script.
function Release-Ref ($ref) { 
    ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject( 
    [System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0) 
    [System.GC]::Collect() 
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
                            }

#Release COM Object
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$a) |     Out-Null

#Clear screen for the final time. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Exit powershell 
exit
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Define "stuck". What exactly is not working? The DNS lookup? Filling the Excel sheet? Sending mail? What are the expected results, and how does that differ from the actual results? Do you get an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Done. :-) Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: How about the line `target="_parent">Creator'` which isn't a valid line? Also, `$objRange2 = $objworksheet.Range("B3:B($Count)")` get rid of the `()` around `$Count`. And something about defining $SMTP for the first time, and referencing itself doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the sorting problem by altering the code to:

```
$objRange = $c.Range("A$($iRow):E$($intRow)")
$objRange2 = $c.Range("B$($iRow):B$($intRow)")
[void] $objRange.Sort($objRange2)
```

Turns out it got stuck on the header in the xml file

Replaced mailing with:

```
$From = "Blocked IP <##@##.##>"
$To = "IT Dept <##@##.##>"
$CC = "Someone <##@##.##"
$Subject = "Blocked IPs for $date ($Count Total)"
#The href should point to the htm file in your iis/apache folder.
$WebLink = $FinalIPAddress+$FileHtmlWeb
$here = "<a href='http://$Weblink'><b>Here</b></a>"
#Define the body of your e-mail, in this case it displays a message and shows the server it is send from with it's local IP.
#A link to the .htm file, how many IP's were blocked and the date of the message.
$body = "Dear <font color=black>$to</font>,<br><br>"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "##@gmail.com"
$Password = "##"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.ReplyTo = $From
$message.Sender = $From
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
$message.from = $username
$message.attachments.add($MailXML)
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.send($message)
```

The saving of the file turned out to be a misguided path.
Since the excel sheet was created from folder1 it wouldnt save instandly to folder 2 since its temp save file would remain in folder1.

Answer (score 1):

> *Exception calling "Sort" with "1" argument(s): "The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."*

Double-check that `$objRange` and `$objRange2` reference the correct ranges:

```
$objRange.Address()
$objRange2.Address()
```

Not much else I can tell you here without seeing your actual data.

---

> *Exception calling "SaveAs" with "1" argument(s): "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C://Folder/BlockedIP/HTML/2014-07-08/0BCEF810'. workbook."*

If the path really were `C://Folder/...` you'd be getting a different exception. Please do not fabricate error messages.

---

> *New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."*

You're confusing [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Not to mention that you don't even need either of them, since you're using `Send-MailMessage` anyway. Just remove the following 5 lines:

```
$SMTP = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($SMTP, 587) 
$SMTP.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$username", "$password"); 
$SMTP.isbodyhtml= $true
$SMTP.Send($From, $To, $Subject, $FileXML, $Body)
```

Comment: Those are the three things I saw too. He obviously modified things to post, since his line numbers in his errors don't match up with his code that he posted. Thanks for writing it up so eloquently, your answer is much easier to read, makes more sense, and is more thorough than my rambling little comment.